# Use local phpunit if installed otherwise fall back to global

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

I have PHPUnit version `5.3.2` installed via composer globally, and version `5.7.19` installed locally in my project. I can run global PHPUnit just by typing `phpunit` and local by `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Is there a way to configure PHPUnit to by default run local installation if it exists, or otherwise fall back to global installation so I don't have to use `vendor/bin/phpunit` each time?

The only solution I came up so far is creating a bash script `phpunit` in project directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
vendor/bin/phpunit $@
```

But then I have to type `./phpunit` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I wasn't that far. So I added following to my `.bashrc`

```
original_phpunit=$(which phpunit)

phpunit() {
    if [ -f vendor/bin/phpunit ]; then vendor/bin/phpunit $@
    else eval "'$original_phpunit' $@"
    fi
}
```

And now it works as I wanted. Hope someone will find it useful!